# Luigi - How to deal with failed workflows

Tags: python, luigi

I am just getting familiar with Luigi, so I apologize if this is an obvious question, but I am having a hard time understanding it from the documentation.

In a situation where I run a workflow with three tasks, and the second task fails, how can I manually re-run the pipeline beginning at the second task? From what I am reading, you can only configure automatic retries. What do you do if all of the auto-retries fail? Do you simply need to kick off a new workflow entirely?

Comment: I don't know your situation exactly, but with how I run luigi all I have had to do is re-run the same script and tasks that are already complete don't get re-run and failed tasks are re-run. I typically fixed what was causing the error then re-ran the same exact script and it picked up from where it left off. Can you just re-run to see what happens or is there potential to cause issues ?

Comment: Got it, so the key is to make the output of each method distinct to that "run" of the workflow, so that restarting will simply pick back up. Will try it out and come back if I have questions, thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 0):

When you run Luigi, the task scheduler checks which tasks have already completed. If a task as already completed, successfully, it won't run that task again.

So if you run it same pipeline again, it should continue where it left off last time, as long as none of the parameter values have changed (which would change the task signature and thus Luigi would create new tasks instead of checking the previous ones, because the same task class executed with different parameters are considered different tasks).